# Extract substrings from a list into a list in Python

Tags: python

I have a Python list like:

```
['user@gmail.com', 'someone@hotmail.com'...]
```

And I want to extract only the strings after @ into another list directly, such as:

```
mylist = ['gmail.com', 'hotmail.com'...]
```

Is it possible? split() doesn't seem to be working with lists.

This is my try:

```
for x in range(len(mylist)):
  mylist[x].split("@",1)[1]
```

But it didn't give me a list of the output.

Comment: Sure it is. Have you tried anything yourself yet? Did you look up how to split a single value, for example?

Comment: I tried split(). in a for loop with index for each one of the elements, but it didn't give me a list of what I want, only a single string.

Comment: In other words, have you tried breaking this problem down into smaller parts that you could attempt to solve one by one?

Comment: @Madno: then your post would be greatly helped if you included that attempt.

Comment: We wanna see code... :)

Comment: I added the code I tried.

Comment: Try `mylist[x] = mylist[x].split("@",1)[1]`. You should replace the value in the list

Comment: It gives me: "IndexError: list index out of range".

Comment: @Madno: then you have values that don't have a `@` character in them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're close, try these small tweaks:

Lists are iterables, which means its easier to use for-loops than you think:

```
for x in mylist:
  #do something
```

Now, the thing you want to do is 1) split `x` at `'@'` and 2) add the result to another list.

```
#In order to add to another list you need to make another list
newlist = []
for x in mylist:
     split_results = x.split('@')
     # Now you have a tuple of the results of your split
     # add the second item to the new list
     newlist.append(split_results[1])
```

Once you understand that well, you can get fancy and use list comprehension:

```
newlist = [x.split('@')[1] for x in mylist]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's my solution with nested for loops:

```
myl = ['user@gmail.com', 'someone@hotmail.com'...]
results = []
for element in myl:
    for x in element:
        if x == '@':
            x =  element.index('@')
            results.append(element[x+1:])
```